# Get Values from HttpRequestException in another application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, httpresponsemessage

I send `Exception` from one web application and get it in another.
How do I can get values from `HttpRequestException` in this case?

send from:

```
context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(apiError.StatusCode)
{
    Content = new ObjectContent<ApiError>(apiError,
       new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), @"application/json")
};
return context;
```

get in another:

```
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    this.logger.LogError(
      string.Format("Ошибка запроса {0}", requestUri.AbsoluteUri),
      LogCategoryRepository.ApiCashdesk,
      e);
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. You just create a class:

```
 public class ErrorDetails
 {
    public string Details { get; set; }
 }
```

And use it:

```
try
            {
                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        ***var error = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ErrorDetails>().ConfigureAwait(false);***
                        throw new HttpRequestException(error.Details);
                    }
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return result;
                }
            }
```